# Windows no longer boots up: bcdedit command likely at fault

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, command-line, boot, multi-boot

I was trying to dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu when I ran into a problem: My system would immediately boot up Windows without bringing up the familiar GRUB menu that gives me a list with Windows or Ubuntu to choose from.

I wanted an easy-fix (huge mistake), so I came across an article that claimed running the following command in a Windows command prompt with admin privileges would fix this issue:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

The article claimed that if any issues arose, this command could be reversed by running these two following commands in the same type of command prompt:

```
bcdedit /deletevalue {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

and:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
```

The article further gave assurances that if one could not boot up Windows, a command prompt from a Windows Recovery USB/CD would work just as well.

Well, that did not work. Now my system no longer boots up Windows--worse yet, when I press F12 and try to access my Windows Boot Manager, all I see is GRUB 2--with no option to boot up Windows. Does anyone know how I can fix this problem?

What I have tried:

1. Followed the instructions from the article: opened a command prompt while booting Windows Repair from a USB. After running the `bcdedit /deletevalue` command, the command prompt told me it did not recognize the command. I am thinking this is possible because: (1) The command prompt is running off a bootable USB, not the partition where the Windows OS is installed on. (2) My version of Windows 10 is German--perhaps the command is different?
2. Tried booting up in both UEFI modes--secure mode on and off. Neither worked.
3. Reverted BIOS to factory settings.

Has anyone had a similar problem? I should add that before applying the above command, Windows 10 would boot up directly at start-up--and it used the normal UEFI with secure mode on.

Comment: did you fixed this?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Is it solved?

Answer (score 1):

The [EFI System Partition (ESP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition) contains the various boot options - those provided by the manufacturer, by Microsoft, and those added by installing Ubuntu. You can access this partition when booting from installation media, or with a tool such as [DiskGenius](https://www.diskgenius.com/), or possibly from Ubuntu. If you know [which of the *.efi* files](https://www.lifewire.com/efi-file-2620983) are being accessed, it is possible to copy and rename them to force the correct boot order.

[image: EFI System Partition]

First, though, try using [efibootmgr](https://www.lifewire.com/change-the-efi-boot-order-efibootmgr-4028027) from Ubuntu to edit the boot options.